# FFmpeg - frame delays double after the audio was added

Tags: ffmpeg, multimedia

single video delays 49ms

`ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M  -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270"  -vcodec libx264 -r 30-g 5  -preset:v ultrafast -tune:v zerolatency -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:80/live/test`

The delay was 100 ms after adding audio.

`ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M  -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270":audio="麦克风 (HD Webcam C270)"  -vcodec libx264 -g 5 -r 30  -acodec aac -preset:v ultrafast -tune:v zerolatency -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:80/live/tao`

Is it normal? Is there any solution to reduce the delay?

Comment: Add `-fflags +nobuffer` before `-i`. You may also want to add `-probesize 500k -analyzeduration 500k` at the same place. Play around with the latter numbers.

Comment: @Gyan It did not reduce the delay. But thanks!